# How to override sfDoctrineGuard validators in order to allow login based on credentials

Tags: authentication, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

As title said I need to modify sfDoctrineGuard validators to allow login based on credentials. I've this users and credentials:

```
username           credential
administrator      super admin
user1              public_access
user2              
user3              public_access
```

I've also two applications: admin and site. So based on this data I need to achieve this:

- user1 and user3 could login in site app but not in admin
- user2 couldn't login in site and either in admin
- administrator could login in admin but not in site

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should copy the `sfGuardValidatorUser` class from `plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/validator` into `lib/validator` and clear the cache.

Than modify it's `doClean` method to check if a user has the required permission.

```
class sfGuardValidatorUser extends sfValidatorBase
{
  // ...

  protected function doClean($values)
  {
    $username = isset($values[$this->getOption('username_field')]) ? $values[$this->getOption('username_field')] : '';
    $password = isset($values[$this->getOption('password_field')]) ? $values[$this->getOption('password_field')] : '';

    $callable = sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_retrieve_by_username_callable');

    if ($username && $callable)
    {
      $user = call_user_func_array($callable, array($username));
    }
    elseif ($username)
    {
      $user = $this->getTable()->retrieveByUsername($username);
    }
    else
    {
      $user = false;
    }

    /** @var $user sfGuardUser */
    if ($user && $user->isAllowedToLogIn(sfConfig::get('sf_app'), $password))
    {
      return array_merge($values, array('user' => $user));
    }

    if ($this->getOption('throw_global_error'))
    {
      throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid');
    }

    throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this, array($this->getOption('username_field') => new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid')));
  }

  // ...
}
```

Than add `isAllowedToLogIn` method to the `sfGuardUser` class:

```
public function isAllowedToLogIn($app, $password)
{
  if ('admin' == $app)
  {
    $hasPermission = $this->getIsSuperAdmin() || $this->hasPermission('admin');
  }
  elseif ('site' == $app)
  {
    $hasPermission = $this->hasPermission('public_access');
  }
  else
  {
    $hasPermission = true;
  }

  return $this->getIsActive() && $this->checkPassword($password) && $hasPermission;
}
```

Modify the permission check part if needed.

I recommend to add an admin group and permission as well and if you can don't use the `is_super_admin` flag.

Comment: where I should add the function isAllowedToLogIn()? I mean in which file(route)?

Comment: @ReynierPM `lib/model/doctrine/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/sfGuardUser.class.php`

Comment: I can enter to admin app as administrator and not as others user but can't enter to site using user1 credentials. I check permissions and all seems to be fine. I check the logs and get this: **CSRF attack detected.**, why?

Comment: nevermind it works perfectly maybe I miss something, I clear the cache, recheck all permissions at sfGuard plugin and now it's work, many thanks, you've got the points and the best answer. Also thanks to Michael Trojanowski

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things here - authentication and authorisation of users.

Authentication means that your users can log into the website, and you have a confirmation that this the right person.

Authorisation filters which content is available to which users (authenticated or not).

So what you are looking for here is to block access to users who should not be able to see the `admin` app, not block the login.

If you block the login part (using validators, your own signing action or whatever) you will only block anonymous users who will want to see your `admin` app. When they try to log in they will be rejected because they are not admins. But if the user logs in to the `site` app and then goes to `admin` there will no additional login required and the user will be granted access (unless you set the proper authorisation).

So what you need is to add a `security.yml` file to your `apps/admin/config` folder with this content:

```
all:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: super_admin
```

If a 'normal' user logs in and tries to navigate to `admin` app he will be denied access.

Comment: Yes, you're right but users can still login and I don't want that. I mean user1 don't have access because his credentials but can still login and I don't want even that, I'm right?

Comment: I just don't see the point in doing that. If you really want to limit the users logging in you can use the code from @1ed's answer. Just remmember that without securing the `admin` app as shown above limiting the login will really be of no use.